# Fitting ideal sheaves and determinant bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra

I am working on a problem in algebraic geometry which comes down to a fact in commutative algebra that I am hoping is well-known.

Suppose $F$ is a coherent sheaf on a smooth variety $S$, and that the support of $F$ has codimension 1.  The support of $F$ can be given a natural scheme structure, corresponding to the Fitting ideal sheaf $Fitt_0(F)$ locally generated by maximal minors of the matrix in a finite presentation of $F$ by trivial bundles.

In my present circumstances I know a bit more about $F$: it locally admits a resolution of the form

$0\to A\to B\to F \to 0$

where $A,B$ are vector bundles of the same rank.  Under this hypothesis, I believe it is relatively straightforward to show that

$Fitt_0(F)^\ast \cong \det F$,

where the determinant is defined in terms of a resolution by vector bundles by the usual trick.

Does anyone know a reference where things like this are considered?  And is my extra hypothesis needed?  (I suspect that perhaps without it the Fitting ideal sheaf may fail to be a line bundle, but I am not sure).

Thanks!

Comment: Assuming that your variety is projective, you may assume that $A$ and $B$ are globally defined.

Comment: @LevBorisov: why is that?

Comment: Take $B$ to be a sum of line bundles $\mathcal O(-d_i)$ that surjects onto $F$. Then the kernel is a vector bundle by projective dimension considerations.

Comment: Have you looked at matrix factorizations?

Comment: @LevBorisov: thank you.  I see now that this is also a consequence of Ex. III.6.5 in Hartshorne, and weaker hypotheses than projective are necessary.  (Presumably the proof is similar to what you suggest, but the goal of this was to cite a reference and avoid a proof in the paper--the result is quite orthogonal to what I am actually doing.)

Comment: @Youngsu: I have not.  What did you have in mind?

Comment: @JackHuizenga: Locally, the conditions for $F$ and $S$ implies that $F$ is a maximal Cohen-Macaulay module of codimension 1. Matrix factorizations by Eisenbud, (D. Eisenbud: Homological algebra on a complete intersection, with an application to group representations, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 260 (1980), 35–64.) gives a relation which you may find useful. Please look at Section 6 in the paper. This material might be in his books Commutative algebra or Geometry of syzygies.

Comment: @JackHuizenga: In order to make my understanding of the question clear, can you define what does it mean by $^*$ in $Fitt_0(F)^*$ and determinant of $F$ in the post?